# Reshape data frame by id and variable type

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'm having trouble rearranging the following data frame:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
   id = rep(1, 4),
   var = paste0(rep(c("firstName",  "secondName"), each= 2), c(rep(1:2, 2))),
   value = c(1:4)
 )
dat2 <- data.frame(
   id = rep(2,3),
   var = paste0(rep(c("firstName", "secondName"), each= 2)[1:3], c(rep(1:2, 
2))[1:3]),
  value = c(5:7)
)
dat = rbind(dat1, dat2)
dat$type = gsub('[0-9]', '', dat$var)
# > dat
# id         var value
# 1  1  firstName1     1
# 2  1  firstName2     2
# 3  1 secondName1     3
# 4  1 secondName2     4
# 5  2  firstName1     5
# 6  2  firstName2     6
# 7  2 secondName1     7
```

I want to get the follow result:

```
id firstName  secondName
 1  1          3 
 1  2          4
 2  5          7
 2  6          NA
```

I've tried `unstack(dat, form = value ~ type)` but it doesn't work.

**Question updated:**
The `firstName1` was supposed to correspond with `secondName1`, so if I change dat2 to

```
  dat2 <- data.frame(id = rep(2,3),var ＝paste0(rep(c("firstName", "secondName"), each= 2)[2:4], c(rep(1:2, 2))[2:4]),value = c(5:7))
# > dat
#    id         var value       type
# 1:  1  firstName1     1  firstName
# 2:  1  firstName2     2  firstName
# 3:  1 secondName1     3 secondName
# 4:  1 secondName2     4 secondName
# 5:  2  firstName2     5  firstName
# 6:  2 secondName1     6 secondName
# 7:  2 secondName2     7 secondName
```

For id = 2, his names should be c(NA, 6) and c(5, 7). So how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better option in my opinion is to use the `rowid`-function from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), id + rowid(type) ~ type, value.var = 'value')[, type := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id firstName secondName
> 1:  1         1          3
> 2:  1         2          4
> 3:  2         5          7
> 4:  2         6         NA
> ```

---

For the updated question:

```
setDT(dat)[, num := gsub('.*([0-9])', '\\1', var)
           ][, dcast(.SD, id + num ~ type, value.var = 'value')
             ][, num := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id firstName secondName
> 1:  1         1          3
> 2:  1         2          4
> 3:  2        NA          6
> 4:  2         5          7
> ```

Comment: Nice. I was considering adding this as a better alternative as the current one in my answer may not work on the real data of OP.

Comment: @mt1022 True. Besides that, using `rowid` is probaby a lot faster (especially on large datasets).

Comment: Here is anther question: the `firstname1` was supposed to correspond with `secondname1`, so if I change dat2 to `dat2 <- data.frame(id = rep(2,3),var = paste0(rep(c("firstName", "secondName"), each= 2)[2:4], c(rep(1:2, 2))[2:4]),value = c(5:7))`, the names of id = 2 is in the wrong order.

Comment: @velvetrock please update your question with an extra example that illustrates your problem, it is not clear to me what you mean with your comment; currently my answer solves the problem as formulated in the question

Answer (score 3):

Try `dcast`:

```
res <- data.table::dcast(
    dat,
    id  + substring(as.character(var), nchar(as.character(var))) ~ type,
    value.var = 'value')

res[2] <- NULL

# > res
#   id firstName secondName
# 1  1         1          3
# 2  1         2          4
# 3  2         5          7
# 4  2         6         NA
```

`substring(as.character(var), nchar(as.character(var)))` is used to get the last character of the second column as a group variable.

Answer (score 3):

with `library(tidyr)`

```
rbind(dat1,dat2) %>% separate(var,c("name","index"),"(?=\\d+$)") %>%
spread(key=name,value=value)
```

#### Result

```
  id index firstName secondName
1  1     1         1          3
2  1     2         2          4
3  2     1         5          7
4  2     2         6         NA
```

#### Note

add `%>% dplyr::select(-index)` in the end if you want to drop col `index`.